# Show fields only when other column does not contain nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores pets and a certain number of vaccines. In one column the identifier, in another column the name of the vaccine and in the third column, the date of completion. In case the date is null, it means that the pet has not received that vaccine yet.

This estructure is the next one:

```
CREATE TABLE pets (
  pet VARCHAR (10), 
  vaccine VARCHAR (50), 
  complete_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG001', 'Adenovirus', '2021-01-03');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG001', 'Parvovirus', '2021-02-03');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG001', 'Leptospirosis', null);
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('CAT774', 'Calcivirosis', '2021-01-06');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('CAT774', 'Panleukopenia', null);
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG002', 'Adenovirus', '2020-12-21');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG002', 'Parvovirus', '2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ('DOG002', 'Leptospirosis', '2021-03-01');
```

| pet | vaccine | complete_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DOG001 | Adenovirus | 2021-01-03 |
| DOG001 | Parvovirus | 2021-02-03 |
| DOG001 | Leptospirosis | null |
| CAT774 | Calcivirosis | 2021-01-06 |
| CAT774 | Panleukopenia | null |
| DOG002 | Adenovirus | 2020-12-21 |
| DOG002 | Parvovirus | 2021-02-01 |
| DOG002 | Leptospirosis | 2021-03-01 |

What I need is a list of **all the pets that do not have a null "date"**, considering **all the vaccines**.

In this example, the result should be simply '**DOG002**' since it is the only animal with all its dates with non-null values.

Comment: `SELECT pet FROM pets WHERE complete_date IS NOT NULL EXCEPT SELECT pet FROM pets WHERE complete_date IS NULL` is one way to do it, though not necessarily the most obvious or efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional aggregate in the `HAVING` would be one method:

```sql
SELECT Pet
FROM dbo.Pets
GROUP BY Pet
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Complete_Date IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Larnu posted what you are looking for (+1)... BUT... just in case you want to see the pet's details.

Just another option is `WITH TIES`.

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  pets
 order by sum(case when complete_date is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by pet)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Pet FROM Pets 
WHERE Pet NOT IN (SELECT Pet FROM Pets WHERE Complete_Date IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

CTE can also be used to achieve the above result

```
with CTE as 
(
 select pet,
 vaccine,
 complete_date,
 SUM(IIF(complete_date is null ,1,0)) over (PARTITION BY pet) as pet_flag  
 from pets
)

select distinct Pet from CTE where
pet_flag = 0
```

Comment: Pet peeve, but `;` is a statement *terminator* not a "beginningator". It goes at the end of **all** your statements not at the start of the ones that require the *prior* one to be properly terminated.

Comment: yeah that right @Larnu - I have corrected it now